# run nodejs forever

Tags: shell, node.js

im runnig an http server using nodejs. i want also the server to run forever, even when my machine restarts,i want node to run again upon restart. so i created a script to put in the

```
/etc/init.d/
```

here is the script

```
#! /bin/sh -e
set -e
PATH=/usr/local/bin/node:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
DAEMON=/opt/node-v0.4.7/examples/app.js
case "$1" in
start) forever start $DAEMON ;;
stop) forever stop $DAEMON ;;
force-reload|restart)
forever restart $DAEMON ;;
*) echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/node {start|stop|restart|force-reload}"
exit 1 ;;
esac
exit 0
```

however when i run

```
/etc/init.d/node
```

i keep getting the same error saying

> /etc/init.d/node: 13: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

can you guys see the error ? i'm sure it's probably some easy syntax error but it's kinda late and i'm really tired.
thanks for the help

Comment: What kind of shell is /bin/sh?

Comment: that was the problem. i dont know why it /bin/sh it should /bin/bash . thanks for pointing out the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create upstart service in Ubuntu(if you use it).
Create myapp.conf in /etc/init and write something like:

```
start on startup
respawn
exec node /path/to/your/script.js
```

Then your app will start after reboot and you can manage it via start and stop commands.
And look at [forever node.js module](https://github.com/indexzero/forever)

Comment: Does it still make sense to use forever if you set the upstart config to respawn?

Comment: I think yes, because forever package is supervisor and can restart your node.js app.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the shebang from:

`#! /bin/sh -e`

To:

`#! /bin/bash`

And now that script works for me.